# OEM installation 18.04 personal files lost

Tags: 18.04, data-recovery, oem

I am new to Ubuntu.
 I Had installed Ubuntu LTS 18.04 but I went with OEM installation.
  At that time after installing Ubuntu I copied some personal files on HDD.
  2 Days later I clicked "Ready to be shipped" Icon, now I can’t locate my personal Files on HDD.

It did be kind of you guys to please help me out retrieve my data

Comment: That's how the [OEM install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview) works. After installation, you can add additional software and drivers, customize settings, etc. This is done using the **temporary** oem user. When you have finished your customizations, you click on _Prepare for shipping to end user_, which will remove the oem user and all of her files. On the next boot, the user configures her system like during a usual installation.

The OEM installation is used to configure the system **before** it is shipped to the end user.